# Export CSV of product with specific column

Tags: magento-1.9, export

From frontend i want to export csv.

I am using this code to export csv

```
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $attributeCodeToSkip = array(
        'approve_product',
        'vendor_customer_id'
    );

    $skipAttrs = array();
    if ($attributeCodeToSkip) {
        foreach ($attributeCodeToSkip as $attributecode) {
            $attributeDetails = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributecode);
            $skipAttrs[]      = $attributeDetails->getAttributeId();
        }
    }
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

    $data = array(
        "entity" => 'catalog_product',
        "file_format" => 'csv',
        "export_filter" => array(
            "vendor_customer_id" => $customer->getId()
        ),
        "skip_attr" => $skipAttrs
    );

    $model = Mage::getModel('importexport/export');
    $model->setData($data);

    return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($model->getFileName(), $model->export(), $model->getContentType());
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store);
```

using this I am getting all information about product except two field which i set in **skip_attr** but i want only **product name,SKU and qty.** in csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this code in your controller to get only **Product name,sku,quantity**

```
$products_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); //get products model
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

    $collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('vendor_customer_id',$customer->getId());

    $csv = '';
    $_columns = array(
        "SKU",
        "Product Name",
        "Qty",
    );
    $datas = array();
    foreach ($_columns as $column) {
        $datas[] = '"'.$column.'"';
    }
    $csv .= implode(',', $datas)."\n";
    $id = array(); 
    foreach ($collection as $collections)
    {
        $id[] = $collections->getId();
    }
    foreach ($id as $pid)
    {
        $prod = $products_model->load($pid);
        $stock_item = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($pid);

        $data['sku'] = $prod->getSku();
        $productName = str_ireplace(',', '|', $prod->getName());
        $data['name'] = $productName;
        $data['qty'] = $stock_item->getQty();
        $csv .= implode(',', $data)."\n";   
    }


    return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('sample.csv', $csv);
```